# Looking for Excel Formula to format the test data

Tags: excel

i have the test data exported from Dynamo DB in the following format. (11/26/2019 18:59:13.523)
So it writes the date and time along with its milliseconds. i need to change the time zone to 12 hours rather 24 hour clock. Can someone guide me how to do that.

Comment: Change the format of the cells to `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000 AM/PM`

Comment: ^^^^^^^^ (assuming the data is an actual date & time and not a text string -- if the latter, you'll need to convert it to the former)

Comment: ^^^^^^ If the later then use Text to Columns on the data tab to do the conversion to the former in mass.

Answer (score 0):

`TEXT()` on that string, and
format it as `'mm/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss.000 AM/PM'` using Ctrl+1, Custom